# Why was the Kree's kill switch so weak?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

Thousands of years ago, Kree experimented on primitive humans to create first *Inhuman Warriors*. Later, the program was abandoned and some Kree Reapers were put in stasis to forever orbit the solar system, in case the need arose to kill the Inhumans. And, its activation system was put on the Earth itself.

In season 3 of Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D., the Hive even activated the Inhuman kill switch on purpose. Although, he had initially said that it was the only weapon which could kill him, he easily managed to kill one Kree Reaper without taking any help from others. Even Daisy was able to kill one Kree Reaper on her own.

Why was Kree's kill switch so weak?

Comment: The Kree suffer heavily from [Villian Decay](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/VillainDecay) throughout the series. The first (live) one we see defeats an Asgardian, yet by the end even Mack and May have no difficulty dispatching them single-handed.

Answer (score 1):

The Kree artifact in question was not a kill switch.

It was a beacon. The beacon, when activated, would call the Kree reapers that were in orbit around earth.

The reason Hive said that it was the only thing that could kill him was that Hive was indeed not more powerful than them before.

But when he signals them, the Kree reaper underestimate him and get killed in the process.

So in summary:

- The "kill switch" was not a kill switch at all.
- The artifact was merely a beacon. It had no capability to kill anyone.
- The reapers signalled by the beacon had been in stasis for a long time, and then underestimated the inhuman threat before them, and hence were easily killed.

Comment: The "Kill Switch" is figurative phrase here.